# Bash script does not wait for user to enter response

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to read a text file (line by line) and take user response in a while loop.
However, the script does not wait to take input. Instead, it just prints all the text to screen.

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "Store $line y or n: "
    read input
    if [ $input == "y" ]
    then
        echo $line >> saved_domains.txt
    fi
done < "urls.txt"
```

The script only prints alternate text lines from the file (Please refer to the image below).

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGK0N.png)

Comment: You never ask the user for input in your script. You just do a `read input`, which causes to read one line from stdin. Your stdin is bound here to `urls.txt`.

Comment: I was assuming that read command stops execution and waits for user input.

Comment: Have a look at the bash man page, the section which says _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_. It describes `read`, `readarray` and other important bash commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
exec 3<&0
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "Store $line y or n: "
    read -r -u3 input
    if [ $input == "y" ]
    then
        echo $line >> saved_domains.txt
    fi
done < "urls.txt"
```